DHCPv4 address doesn't load on Ubuntu Server setup
So, in the the installer for Ubuntu Server (I tried both 22 and 24) I cannot seem to get a IPv4 address at all. In the "Network Configuration" step, I have selected DHCP as the IPv4 method. I can press "Done", it doesnt show the continue without network button and I do have a network connection both in the installer and the installed os, but I dont have an IPv4 address to connect to via SSH later on. In the installer, the DHCPv4 field only shows an eternally spinning line. Enabling DHCPv6 works just fine and gives me an address, but I need IPv4.
The server (an HP Z240 with Intel) is connected via LAN directly to my router (And I know both the cable and Port are fine)The mentioned page in the Ubuntu Server Installer

So I'm just stupid. I didn't realize that not all routers automatically assign an IP address to devices. So I just needed to set the IPv4 setting to manual and enter my router's data.
